# How can I filter (with multiple combinations) the data of a table?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter

my Angular project has a problem.
I have 4 select boxes in which you select different filters:

- office worker
- project name
- employee
- activities

My problem is that I find it difficult to predict all possible filter combinations
example:
employee-project name, employee-type, employee-activity ... and many more.

I've tried using filters, but it doesn't seem to give me correct data.

```
  entities: Activity[],
  { query, employee, type, project, date_from, date_to }: { query: string, employee: string[] , type : string[], project: string[],date_from: Date, date_to: Date },
): Activity[] {
  
    return employee || type|| project?
    entities.filter(e => 
      employee?.indexOf(`${e.employee.firstName.toLowerCase()} ${e.employee.lastName.toLowerCase()}`)>-1 
    
  
      ).filter(e => {type?.indexOf(`${e.type.name.toLowerCase()}`)>-1})
      :entities


}
```

This is the approach I am trying to adopt, so that if an array (for example employed) is empty, the next filtering (on the type) is carried out.

Comment: Are you really using Angular 1.x? That's how you've tagged this q...

Comment: sorry, I have updated. i use last angular version.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can create a filterObject

```
filter={officeWorker:..,projectName:..,employed:...,activities:..}
```

The property can be null or has a value, then you simple use the way `(!filter.property || x.property.indexOf(filter.property)>-1) &&`

```
  this activitiesFiltered=this.activities.filter(x=>{
      (!filter.officeWorker || x.officeWorker.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.officeWorker)>-1) &&
      (!filter.projectName|| x.projectName.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.projectName)>-1) &&
       ....
  })
```

I make a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g7bjal?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: mmm no, in this way it search only if i complete all select box.

Comment: I added a fool stackblitz